# Couldn't detect already defined method

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, oop, methods

I have a text file `file1.txt`. I want to perform some operations on it.
So, I wrote the following code.

```
class alpha:
    def __init__(self,name):
           self.name = name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name2
    def process(self):
         #code
         name2 = name2.split()
         return name2
    def first(self):
         global name2
         with open(self.name,'r') as name2:
             b = process()
             name2= b(name2)

c = alpha("file1.txt")
c.process()
print(c.first())
```

But the program is getting an error: "process is not defined"

How can I rectify this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even after ingvar 's fix, you still need won't get anything out of `print(c.first())`, because that method has no return value. You might want to change that line to refer to an instance variable, or add a `return` to `first(self)`

Comment: Why did you reject my suggested edit? Since you fixed the error in the question code in your edit that I intended to rollback, the question doesn't make any sense anymore. The error message is not actually produced by the code and the answer below doesn't match the problem description anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create object of a class in order to call methods:

```
a = alpha("file1.txt")
print(a.first())
```

Also note that you have few mistakes in `alpha` class:

```
class alpha:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def process(self, file_content):
        return file_content.split()  # spilt file content into separate lines

    def first(self):
        with open(self.name, 'r') as fl:
            name2 = fl.read()  # read file content in name2 
            name2 = self.process(name2)  # process content

            return name2
```

Comment: Hey @ingvar, I've tried it. But it is still giving an error: "local variable name2 referenced before assignment. I've tried ```def first(self): global name2```.Please refer my question for edited code. Thanks

Comment: You use name2 in process method, but it's undeclared. What is name2, probably it should be self.name? Or self.name2?

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve with your code?

Comment: No, @ingvar. name2 is the str object holding the text of "name" . I want to perform operations on the contentes of name i.e. name2. So, I used it in process method. Is it wrong?

Comment: In this code, I'm trying to perform few operations on the file contents in the file "name". I want to read it using first() method. And then I want to invoke process() method to perform certain operations and return the final file contents. Thanks @ingvar

Comment: now the error is process is miising an positional argument  : file_content @ingvar

Comment: @ramusuri Sorry, forgot to remove `process` call from first code snippet, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks a lot. Absolute genius @ingvar